# How to send multiple objects with Outbound Message?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

Outbound Message is great for simple stuff. If I just needed to send an Opportunity, then Outbound Message would give me all the functionality that I need. And I could set up a Flow, triggered on create or edit, that would then send the Outbound Message.

But I need to send some fields from Opportunity, and also the AccountID, and also some LineItems.

Can all this be done with Outbound Message? Or should I resort to custom Apex programming? If I should use custom Apex programming, can anyone suggest how to get started on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outbound Message can include a Session Id that you can use to query Salesforce with the REST/SOAP APIs. This is often more convenient than writing Apex, since you already have to write code for the endpoint anyways.